# What is blocking my pitcure in my website? HTML, CSS

Tags: html, css, carousel

I want my pictures to be complete and centered but there is something blocking it, is a slider for 9 pictures and each picture has a box that holds inside the picture.

The main problem is the plantilla that holds the picture, the thing is tha I've been trying to make it bigger so the image can occupy the whole center of the page

This is part of the code that I have in my css

```
div.carousel .col-md-4.animation-element {
 min-width: 400px !important;
 margin-left: 0%; 
}

.carousel-indicators {
    margin-bottom: 10%;
}

.carousel .item{
    margin: 0 auto;    
}
```

and this is the [Website](http://caribu.com.ve/caribu.html#Tragos)

I've tried to change the css of bootstrap but not even that worked, I've put the configuration "margin: 0 auto;" also but nothing

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: Please go read [ask].

Comment: You need to be clear, we see a slideshow with multiple pictures? Do you mean the container that holds them all? Note a link to a website isn't a good idea since your website can vanish at any time and doesn't help anyone else but you. Use a concise example instead.

Comment: I updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.carousel-inner {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

I removed the overflow: hidden; and it looks fine to me.

Comment: I removed it from bootstrap.min.css and it works just fine in firefox :)